# Call a function on Valid Blur

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/tNcnSYvNr0YC58FjsNKe)

How can i trigger function call on blur only if element is valid has no other error?

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="order" ng-model="order" name="order" class="form-control" 
    ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" ng-minlength="9" maxlength="9"
    required="" ng-blur="something()"  />
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.something=function(){
      if($scope.routingNumber.$valid)
        alert("yippie");
    }
});
```

Comment: Like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/oiGKFq?p=preview Probably i misunderstood your question...

Comment: Is your issue solved? Have you tried PSL plunker and the answer I provided?

Comment: sorry forgot to update it. Yup it was solved :) thanks

Answer (score 6):

Here you go: http://plnkr.co/edit/g4ecmWToQPbOKAk3XvNt?p=preview (complete form)
http://plnkr.co/edit/Zep8D4AXvkzwpqcFFXjR?p=preview (order field only)

You just have to pass your `form` to your `something` method.

```
<input type="text" id="order" ng-model="order" name="order" class="form-control" 
 ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" ng-minlength="9" maxlength="9"
 required="" ng-blur="something(myform)"  />
```

And in your JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.something = function(form) {
    if (form.order.$valid) {
      alert("yippie");
    }
  }
});
```

You can find more info about form validation and errors in the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: I still have some validations going on after this input so form will not be valid always. What if i want to check for this input only and call some method on valid input?